# document.createElement(); Is there a list of elements I can create?

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to use the document.createElement method to populate a dynamic form and Im wondering which kind of elements I can create.

I know I can use tags such as "p" and "li" to create paragraphs and list items, but I was wondering if there's a way to create a standard line break, and what other elements I can create with this method.

Comment: You can create any kind of element that exists in HTML.

Comment: You can also create elements that don't exist, which seems somewhat paradoxical now that I've typed it.

Comment: [Here is some more information about `.createElement`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create any element you like, including ones that haven't been defined yet. There's a list of [HTML elements here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/index.html#elements-1), [SVG elements here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/eltindex.html), and so on, but you can do whatever you want. If you create an element that the browser doesn't know about, it will add that to its list of elements it knows about (for that page), and use very boring default styling.

Gratuitous example:

```js
var e, s;

e = document.createElement('foo');
e.innerHTML = "I'm a <code>foo</code> element.";
document.body.appendChild(e);

e = document.createElement('foo');
e.innerHTML = "I'm another <code>foo</code> element.";
document.body.appendChild(e);

s = getComputedStyle(e).display;
e = document.createElement('div');
e.innerHTML = "<code>foo</code>'s default <code>display</code> property value is: " + s;
document.body.appendChild(e);
```